# Access data via BigQuery in python

Tags: python, file, google-bigquery

I am trying to access data in python using bigquery api , here is my code.

I have placed the pem file inside the same folder but script returns an error **"googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/digin-1086/queries?alt=json returned "Not found: Table digin-1086:dataset.my_table">**

```
 from bigquery import get_client
    # BigQuery project id as listed in the Google Developers Console.
    project_id = 'digin-1086'
    # Service account email address as listed in the Google Developers Console.
    service_account = '77441948210-4fhu1kc1driicjecriqupndkr60npnh@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
    # PKCS12 or PEM key provided by Google.
    key = 'Digin-d6387c00c5a'
    client = get_client(project_id, service_account=service_account,
                        private_key_file=key, readonly=True)
    # Submit an async query.
    job_id, _results = client.query('SELECT * FROM dataset.my_table LIMIT 1000')
    # Check if the query has finished running.
    complete, row_count = client.check_job(job_id)
    # Retrieve the results.
    results = client.get_query_rows(job_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it can't find your table, nothing to do with the pem file. You need to make the table exits in the dataset.

Comment: @Sajeetharan-MSFT - Can you help me with this related post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57768635/unable-to-download-data-from-google-bigquery-using-python

Answer (score 0):

To access data via BigQuery in python you can do the following:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport import requests


credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    r'filelocation\xyz.json')

project_id = 'abc'

client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials,project=project_id)


query_job = client.query("""
  SELECT *
  FROM tabename
  LIMIT 10""")
results = query_job.result()

for row in results:
        print(row)}
```